# Domain and Range problem(plane)

Tags: calculus, plane-curves

Consider the function $z = \ln{(y + 1)}+\sqrt{x-3}$. Find the domain and range, and sketch the domain in the plane.

Comment: For what values are the functions log and sqrt defined? When $x \rightarrow 0$ what happens to them? And when $x$ gets larger?

Answer (score 0):

See that $\sqrt{a}$ is defined on the real plane for all $a\geq0$. So, $\sqrt{x-3}$ exists only for $\boxed{x\geq3}$. Then, $ln(b)$ is defined for all $b>0$. So, $\boxed{y>(-1)}$. The sketching and the range parts are trivial now that the domain is given.